# Is there a way to sumif over multiple lines in excel?

Tags: excel, criteria, sumifs

I'm attempting to sum based on two criteria in a line, and taking the sum of a value below it. In reference to the screenshot included, I am trying to find the sum of the trim column on SAT 04.

To do this, I want to sum by the criteria of 'Grey Ash' under boards, and 'Standard' under trim, but only take the values from the trim column. I can't find a way to do this using SUMIF and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: What formula did you use that didn't work and in which cell did you add it?

Comment: It would also be useful to know what the expected output should be

Comment: What about sumifs(), that allows multiple criteria, such as boards, trim and date.